# accessing list element of a list which is stored in var through request attribue

Tags: java, javascript, spring

I have set list through request attribute as `request.setAttribute("webServicel",webService_list);` , webService_list contains `[getpkg,getActive,getEligible etc.]`. I want to access each element of list in javascript. Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var service ='$webServicel.remove(0)';  
    document.forms[0].operations.options[i].text = service;
    document.forms[0].operations.options[i].value = service;
}
```

But each time I am getting getpkg set in var service. Please let me know what I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Your For loop is **Javascript for loop** not a **JSP for loop**

So `$webServicel.remove(0)` will be replaced with value of first element in the list and then below response is returned to browser

```
for(var i = 0; i <5; i++){
    var service ='getPkg';  
    document.forms[0].operations.options[i].text =service;
    document.forms[0].operations.options[i].value =service;
}
```

**Use the below approach instead**

```
<select name="operations">
<c:forEach var="webServiceItem" items="${webService_list}">
<option value="$webServiceItem" > $webServiceItem </option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: then how should i get all elements in list

Comment: I have added the approach in my answer.

Comment: i cna't use directly in html bcoz, i want opeerations drop down to be populated on condition which i m doing through switch-   switch(service)
 {  case "webservice":                            
      for(var i = 0; i < $noofwebservices; i++) {        var service ='$webServicel.remove(0)';        document.forms[0].operations.options[i].text =service;         }
 break;
   case "background"://code......
  default://code......                          
  }

Comment: Try to use this then:- <c:forEach var="webServiceItem" items="${webService_list}" varStatus="status">
    document.forms[0].operations.options[${status.index}].text = ${webServiceItem};
    document.forms[0].operations.options[${status.index}].value = ${webServiceItem};
</c:forEach>

Comment: Inside the for loop ,try this
var opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.text = ${webServiceItem};
opt.value = ${webServiceItem};
document.forms[0].operations.add(opt);